# why won't \foreach work correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

why can not some lines(red ones) be drawn?

[image]

the following is my codes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);
\draw  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);
 \foreach \x in {-0.8,1,...,10.9}
 \foreach \y in {0.2,2,...,7.4}
  \draw  (\x ,\y)  --(\x+0.9 ,\y);
\foreach \l in {0.6,2.4,...,9.6}
   \foreach \m in {-0.2,1.6,...,8.8}
    \draw (\l,\m) -- (\l,\m+0.9);
     \foreach \x in {0.1,1.9,...,9.1}
 \foreach \y in {1.1,2.9,...,6.5}
  \draw  (\x ,\y)  --(\x+0.9 ,\y);
\foreach \l in {1.5,3.3,...,10.5}
   \foreach \m in {0.7,2.5,...,6.1}
    \draw(\l,\m) -- (\l,\m+0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another question: are there any simpler\better methods drawing these lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should take into account rounding errors. So enlarge the last value a bit, e.g. to 10.51.

Beside this I would use integers for the steps and then calculate the values. E.g. for your last one:

```
\foreach \l in {1,2,...,6} %
   \foreach \m in {0,1,...,3} %
    \draw(1.5+1.8*\l,0.7+1.8*\m) -- (1.5+1.8*\l,0.7+1.8*\m+0.9);
```

Comment: Great, those four lines appear. Thanks a lot. The other question, do you have better method simplifying the codes?

Answer (score 9):

A different approach to drawing such patterns, using just two nested loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);
\draw  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);

\newcommand\dx{0.9} % horizontal distance between the line centers
\newcommand\dy{0.9} % vertical distance between the line centers
\pgfmathsetmacro\lx{\dx/2} % half length of horizontal line
\pgfmathsetmacro\ly{\dy/2} % half length of vertical line

\foreach \x in {-2,...,15} {
   \foreach \y in {-1,...,9} {
     \pgfmathsetmacro\ifhoriz{ifthenelse((-1)^(\x+\y)<0,0,1)}
     \ifnum \ifhoriz=0
       \draw (\x*\dx-\lx,\y*\dy) -- (\x*\dx+\lx,\y*\dy);
     \else
       \draw (\x*\dx,\y*\dy-\ly) -- (\x*\dx,\y*\dy+\ly);
    \fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or if the spacing and line length is always the same for x and y, you can make do with a single `\draw`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);
\draw  (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);

\newcommand\dx{0.9} % distance between center of lines in pattern
\pgfmathsetmacro\lx{\dx/2} % half length of lines in pattern

\foreach \x in {-2,...,15} {
   \foreach \y in {-1,...,9} {
       \draw [rotate around={ifthenelse((-1)^(\x+\y)<0,0,90):(\x*\dx,\y*\dx)}]
            (\x*\dx-\lx,\y*\dx) -- (\x*\dx+\lx,\y*\dx);
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, instead of using explicit x and y values in the loop, I use integers as Ulrike does in her answer. To decide whether to draw a horizontal or vertical line, I calculate `(-1)^(\x+\y)`, where `\x` and `\y` are the integers. If you write up a matrix of those values, it will look like

```
y\x  |  1  2  3  4  5
---------------------
1    |  1 -1  1 -1  1 
2    | -1  1 -1  1 -1
3    |  1 -1  1 -1  1
4    | -1  1 -1  1 -1
```

So every other 1 and -1, along both axes.

In the first case, I use `ifthenelse((-1)^(\x+\y)<0,0,1)` to set the macro `\ifhoriz` to either 0 or 1, and then I use `\ifnum` to draw a horizontal line if `\ifhoriz` is 0, and a vertical line if it is 1.

In the second case I draw a horizontal line, but I use a similar `ifthenelse` statement to rotate the line either 0 or 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you very much! excellent computing power! but i can not understand your codes, where can I find the detained explanation of your codes, e.g., your expression.

Comment: @dozer I can add some more explanation later tonight. The key thing is `(-1)^(\x+\y)` I suppose. Consider `\x` and `\y` as indices of a matrix, one giving the row number, the other the column number. If `\x+\y` is an odd number, `(-1)^(\x+\y) = -1`, if `\x+\y` is an even number then `(-1)^(\x+\y) = 1`. This makes the pattern `-1 1 -1 1 ..` along both rows and columns.  The `ifthenelse` and `\ifnum` is for making the code do different things depending on the whether we have `1` or `-1`.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a `\foreach` you could use a new defined `pattern`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, patterns}

\tikzset{
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=1pt
    }

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchthickness]{myhatch}
{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{18mm}{18mm}}
{\pgfpoint{18mm}{18mm}}
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0mm}{4.5mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{9mm}{4.5mm}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{9mm}{13.5mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{18mm}{13.5mm}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.5mm}{9mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4.5mm}{18mm}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{13.5mm}{0mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{13.5mm}{9mm}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[pattern=myhatch, pattern color=red] (0,0) rectangle (10.8,7.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another very good method! Thank you very much!